# Stability of a scheme for one way wave equation.

Tags: finite-differences

*Multiplying the scheme*
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{v_m^{n+1} - v_m^n}{k} + \dfrac{a}{2}\left(\dfrac{v_{m+1}^{n+1} - v_m^{n+1}}{h} + \dfrac{v_m^n - v_{m-1}^n}{h}\right) = 0
\end{equation*}
*by* $v_m^{n+1} + v_m^n$ *and summing over all values of* $m$, *obtain the relation*
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \left[\left(1 - \frac{a \lambda}{2}\right) |v_m^{n+1}|^2 + \frac{a \lambda}{2} v_m^{n+1} v_{m+1}^{n+1}\right] = \sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \left[\left(1 - \frac{a \lambda}{2}\right) |v_m^n|^2 + \frac{a \lambda}{2} v_m^n v_{m+1}^n\right].
\end{equation*}
*Conclude that the scheme is stable for* $a\lambda < 1$.

Note that $\lambda = \frac{k}{h}$. Question is from Strikwerda's Finite Difference Schemes and PDEs, page 33.

I obtained second equality but couldn't go further. Without posting the whole solution, tips are welcome.

Thanks for your time.